# How to update Registry with REG ADD command

Tags: windows-7, command-line, remote-desktop, windows-registry

I need to do set this registry value from command line:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CredentialsDelegation]
"AllowSavedCredentialsWhenNTLMOnly"=dword:00000001
"ConcatenateDefaults_AllowSavedNTLMOnly"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CredentialsDelegation\AllowSavedCredentialsWhenNTLMOnly]
"1"="TERMSRV/* "
```

I can't seem to get the REG ADD command right for this.

I am trying to allow saved password for RDP connections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general syntax (as shown in `reg add /?`) is:

```
reg add <key> [/v <value>] [/t <type>] [/d <data>]
```

So your .reg file corresponds to:

```
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CredentialsDelegation /v AllowSavedCredentialsWhenNTLMOnly /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000001
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CredentialsDelegation /v ConcatenateDefaults_AllowSavedNTLMOnly /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000001
reg add HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CredentialsDelegation\AllowSavedCredentialsWhenNTLMOnly /v 1 /t REG_SZ /d "TERMSRV/*"
```

*(`HKLM` is a shortcut for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`.)*

Of course you could just `reg import` the same .reg file… or use Group Policy, if you're trying to do this within Active Directory.